# Maximal interval of existence for autonomous systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering if anybody could give me a small clarification on Theorem 3.1 of Kelley and Peterson (see p. 101 of [this book](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CGMQFjAF&url=http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MC_Calculus/MCde_Differential%2520equations/Kelley%2520W.,%2520Peterson%2520A.%2520The%2520theory%2520of%2520differential%2520equations..%2520Classical%2520and%2520qualitative%2520%282ed.,%2520Springer,%25202010%29%28ISBN%25201441957820%29%28O%29%28436s%29_MCde_.pdf&ei=FL9eU8vMOcOCOOOVgaAD&usg=AFQjCNHxZJIZ6u7FE0GXIT5LrRXZfrHePw&sig2=Bnvq9hsbrWo9rQFnXfnwmw)). Consider an initial value problem $$\dot{x}=f(x) \qquad x(0)=x_{0}, $$ where $f:D\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a continuous vector function on the open set $D\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The theorem then says that a solution exists on a maximal interval $-\infty\leq \alpha<\omega\leq \infty$; moreover, if $\omega<\infty$, then $\lim_{t\to\omega}\|x(t)\|=\infty$.

Does this mean that if $D$ is bounded, then necessarily $\omega=\infty$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see such a theorem in the book.  Theorem 3.1 has $f$ defined on all of $\mathbb R^n$. Maybe you are referring to an older edition, and the issue was fixed since then?

As stated in your post,  the result is false. As soon as $x$ exits $D$, we cannot continue the solution since $f(x)$ is no longer defined. One-dimensional example: $D=(-1,1)$ and $f(x)=3$. Starting with $x(0)=0$, we have the solution $x(t)=3t$ with the maximal interval of existence $(-1/3,1/3)$.