# If $f$ and $g$ are bounded, then every solution of the autonomous system of differential equations is defined for $t \in \mathbb R$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, reference-request, dynamical-systems

Consider the system of autonomous differential equations (autonomous system of differential equations?)

$$x' = f(x,y)$$

$$y' = g(x,y)$$

where $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$

Let $f$ and $g$ have first partial derivatives that exist and are continuous in $\mathbb R^3$.

Let $(u(t),v(t))$ be a maximal solution of the system such that it is defined on some interval $I$ whose endpoint contains $\alpha$, which I guess means that $t \in$ one of the following:

1. $$\color{red}{(}\alpha, R\color{red}{)}$$
2. $$\color{red}{(}L, \alpha\color{red}{)}$$

where

1. $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ (not $\color{red}{\overline{\mathbb R}}$?)
2. $R,L \in \overline{\mathbb R}$, $R > \alpha$ and $L < \alpha$
3. $\color{red}{(}, \color{red}{)}$ may, respectively, be $\color{red}{[}, \color{red}{]}$

It can be shown that

> **Theorem**: $$\lim_{t \to \alpha} \sqrt{u(t)^2 + v(t)^2} = \infty$$

Using the above theorem, we must prove that

> **Proposition**: If $f$ and $g$ are bounded, then every solution of the autonomous system is defined for $t \in \mathbb R$.

---

I have no idea how to start this, but I guess:

---

1. what the proposition is saying is that if we include the assumption that $f$ and $g$ are bounded, then we can have $\alpha \in \color{red}{\overline{\mathbb R}}$ in the maximal solution described above.

It looks like we can't necessarily have $\alpha \in \color{red}{\overline{\mathbb R}}$ because if $f$ or $g$ isn't bounded, then we could have $x' = \infty$ or $y' = \infty$.

However, I guess that that won't happen if $f$ and $g$ are bounded. That's what we're trying to prove?

---

2. This is the 3D version of something that would have a conclusion like

   $$\lim_{t \to \alpha} |u(t)| = \infty$$

where $u(t), t \in (\alpha, R)$ or $(L, \alpha)$ is a maximal solution of

$$x' = f(x)$$

where $x = x(t)$

---

Is that right?

Please suggest how I might prove this.

---

What I tried based on Julián Aguirre's answer:

Let $(u(t), v(t))$ be defined on some interval $I$ whose endpoint contains $\alpha$. Let $t, t_0 \in I$.

Observe that

$$u(t) = u(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^tf(u(s),v(s))\,ds$$

and

$$v(t) = v(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^tg(u(s),v(s))\,ds$$

Let $f$ and $g$ be bounded, respectively, by $M_f$ and $M_g$. Define $M := \max\{M_f, M_g\}$. Then, we have:

$$u(t)^2 = \left(u(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^tf(u(s),v(s))\,ds\right)^2$$

$$ = u(t_0)^2+\left(\int_{t_0}^tf(u(s),v(s))\,ds\right)^2 + 2\left(\int_{t_0}^tf(u(s),v(s))\right)$$

$$ \le u(t_0)^2+\left(\int_{t_0}^t M \,ds\right)^2 + 2\left(\int_{t_0}^t M \right)$$

$$ \le u(t_0)^2+(M(t-t_0))^2 + 2 M (t-t_0)$$

///ly for $v$ we have:

$$v(t)^2 \le v(t_0)^2+(M(t-t_0))^2 + 2 M (t-t_0)$$

Thus,

$$\sqrt{u(t)^2 + v(t)^2} \le \sqrt{u(t_0)^2+(M(t-t_0))^2 + 2 M (t-t_0) + v(t_0)^2+(M(t-t_0))^2 + 2 M (t-t_0)}$$

$$\to \lim_{t \to \alpha} \sqrt{u(t)^2 + v(t)^2} \le \lim_{t \to \alpha}  \sqrt{u(t_0)^2+(M(t-t_0))^2 + 2 M (t-t_0) + v(t_0)^2+(M(t-t_0))^2 + 2 M (t-t_0)} = \sqrt{u(t_0)^2+(M(\alpha-t_0))^2 + 2 M (\alpha-t_0) + v(t_0)^2+(M(\alpha-t_0))^2 + 2 M (\alpha-t_0)} < \infty$$

I guess this means that we don't have to worry about $\sqrt{u(t)^2 + v(t)^2}$ blowing up, but how does this mean that $(u(t),v(t))$ is defined $\forall \ t \ \in \ \mathbb R$?

---

Might the proof of the theorem be helpful? The theorem is apparently proven in a book by someone named Coddington. I can't find anything like that in the Coddington books I've found online:

1. [Linear ODE by Coddington and Carlson](http://gibbs.if.usp.br/%7Emarchett/fismat2/linear-ode_coddington-carlson.pdf)
2. [An Introduction to ODE by Coddington](https://www.scribd.com/doc/183346090/Earl-Coddington-An-introduction-to-Ordinary-Differential-Equations-pdf)

---

Possibly relevant questions:

1. [Autonomous system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003244/autonomous-system)
2. [Maximal interval of existence for autonomous systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773387/maximal-interval-of-existence-for-autonomous-systems)

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ be a bound of $f$ and $g$ and $t_0\in(L,\alpha)$. Then
$$
|u(t)|=\Bigl|u(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^tf(u(s),v(s))\,ds\Bigr|\le|u(t_0)|+M\,(t-t_0), \quad t_0\le t<\alpha.
$$
Similarly for $v$. This implies that $\sqrt{u(t)^2+v(t)^2}$ cannot go to $\infty$ as $t\to\alpha$. In view of the Theorem, $\alpha$ must be $\infty$.

Comment: How do you know

$$|u(t)|=\Bigl|u(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^tf(s,u(s),v(s))\,ds\Bigr|$$? Also did you mean $$|u(t)|=\Bigl|u(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^tf(\color{red}{u(s),v(s)})\,ds\Bigr|$$?

Comment: Well I guess $u(t)=u(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^tf(u(s),v(s)) \to u'(t) = f(u(t),v(t))$, but how do you know the converse is true?

Comment: Yes, but since the question says that $f$ has partial derivetives in $\mathbb{R}^3$...

Comment: $u$ is a primitive of $u'$. Do you know how to compute definite integrals?

Comment: I'm guessing you did $$\frac{du}{dt} = f(u(t),v(t))$$ $$\to du = f(u(t),v(t)) dt$$ $$\to \int_{t_0}^{t} du = \int_{t_0}^{t} f(u(s),v(s)) ds $$ ? If not, then what? If so, how again can we just add those bounds $\int_{t_0}^{t}$? I forgot how to solve ODEs with bounds in integration. Iirc, we integrate indefinitely then use initial conditions, if any, at the end.

Comment: Since $u$ and $v$ are a solution, $u'(t)=f(u(t),v(t))$. That's all.

Comment: Wait, how do you know that $(u(t),v(t))$ is defined $\forall \ t \ \in \ \mathbb R$? I edited my question

Comment: Why did you point out that $f$ has partial derivatives in $\mathbb R^3$ ? I mean, to what was that responding/addressing?

Comment: I know that $u'(t) = f(u(t),v(t))$...to what is this responding/addressing? Also, how do you know we can use $\int_{t_0}^{t}$ instead of just $\int$ ?

Comment: [Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), Newton-Leibniz formula or Barrow's rule.

Comment: re FTC2, oh lol k thanks. so what about the other questions?

Comment: The result is velid for general systems with $n$ unknows and $n$ equations $x'=f(x)$, $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$.

Comment: What do you mean? I asked how you know that $(u(t),v(t))$ is defined $\forall \ t \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: What do you mean by 'in view of the theorem' ? FYI OPs don't get notified of answer edits